# Why does it says that its missing positional argument?

Tags: python, discord.py

Okay, so I got code like this:

```
groups = ['Z208', 'D204']

def show_next_lesson(self, group):
    workbook = load_workbook(filename=f'/home/xyz/Desktop/{group}.xls')
    sheet = workbook.active
    print(sheet)

class Wwsi(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.command()
    async def nl(self, ctx):
        for role in ctx.author.roles:
            x = str(role)
            if x in groups:
                sheet = x
                show_next_lesson(sheet)
```

It returns error `Missing positional argument "group" at function call`
So basically `sheet` variable is empty? However, if I do `print(sheet)` it actually returns number of group. I don't really understand how does it work, would appreciate any advice ;)

Comment: `show_next_lesson` is not in a class, so `self` is a normal name

Comment: Oh, I see :D thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would move the `show_next_lesson()` into your Class, it would work:

```
class Wwsi(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    def show_next_lesson(self, group):
       workbook = load_workbook(filename=f'/home/xyz/Desktop/{group}.xls')
       sheet = workbook.active
       print(sheet)

    @commands.command()
    async def nl(self, ctx):
        for role in ctx.author.roles:
            x = str(role)
            if x in groups:
                sheet = x
                self.show_next_lesson(sheet)
```

Comment: Yeah, I see it now :D `self` keyword is the key. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Rizonn `self` is not a keyword.  It is just a name used by convention to refer to the object instance that is calling the method.  So you should expect any function definition with `self` as the first argument to be a method of a class.